# CSS add background image's width and height

Tags: css, size, background-image

Is there any trick or possibility to add css background-image:; image width and height?

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the background-size property:

```
#your_div
{
  background:url(your_image.png);
  background-size:80px 60px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: omg never heard about that, maybe my ide has not in suggest list :/ thx!

Comment: Probably because it's a new CSS3 property, and it doesn't have much browser support.